# How can I dynamically enable or show navigation items in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have an Aurelia app with a router and nav bar. I need to be able to dynamically show or enable those routes in the nav bar based on the state of the app. I've attempted to use a method like `nav: isVisible()`, or `show.bind` binding with a custom `settings` property in the route config. Neither of these will dynamically update the nav view during navigation. How can I get the nav to update on demand?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if this is the *right* way, but I found that binding to my custom `visible` member on the route config settings and updating it on navigation like this works:

```
this.eventAggregator.subscribe('router:navigation:processing', ()=>{
      if (this.session.topic != null)
        router.routes.find(r => r.name === 'selectMovie').settings.visible = true;
});
```

As clean as Aurelia has been so far, however, I'd expect a built in way to do this.